# Rx.Subject loses events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx

Can anybody explain what the differents between these 3 variants?

http://jsfiddle.net/8vx2g3fr/2/

1. First works as excpect, all events are processed.
2. But second loses last event (3)
3. Third loses second event (2)

Could you please help me to understand what the issue is and how to make the third variant process all events?

## 1

```
let bs = new Rx.Subject();
bs
    .subscribe(v=>{
        console.log("in", v);
        if (v % 2 == 0) {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log(" out", v, "->" , v + 1);
                bs.next(v+1);
            }, 0);
        }
    });

bs.next(0);
bs.next(2);
```

Output:

```
in 0
in 2
 out 0 -> 1
in 1
 out 2 -> 3
in 3
```

## 2

```
let bs2 = new Rx.Subject();
bs2
    .subscribe(v=>{
        console.log("in", v);
        if (v % 2 == 0) {            
            Rx.Observable.interval(0).take(1)
                .map(()=>{console.log(" out", v, "->" , v + 1);return v+1;})
                .subscribe(bs2);
        }
    });

bs2.next(0);
bs2.next(2);
```

Output:

```
in 0
in 2
 out 0 -> 1
in 1
 out 2 -> 3
```

## 3

```
let bs3 = new Rx.Subject();
bs3
    .switchMap(v=>{
        console.log("in", v);
        if (v % 2 == 0) {            
            return Rx.Observable.interval(0).take(1)
                .map(()=>{console.log(" out", v, "->" , v + 1);return v+1;});
        }

    return Rx.Observable.empty();     
    }).subscribe(bs3);

bs3.next(0);
bs3.next(2);
```

Output:

```
in 0
in 2
 out 2 -> 3
in 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all is in fact expected behavior.

The confusing thing is what happens when you reuse `Subject`and an operator such as `take()` multiple times.

Operator `take(1)` takes just a single value and send `complete` notification. This notification is received by the `Subject` because of `.subscribe(bs2)`. Now comes the most important part.
When a `Subject` receives a `complete` or `error` notification it marks itself as stopped. This means it **will never remit any items or notifications** which is correct and expected behavior in Rx. Notifications `complete` or `error` have to be the last emissions.

So the `Subject` is completed by the first `take(1)` which is triggered by value `0` (the `bs2.next(0)` call).

Then when value `2` triggers the second run of the `Observable.interval(0).take(1)` it's received by the `Subject` but it's automatically ignored because the `Subject` is already marked as stopped.

The process in you third demo is exactly the same.

You can see it in the source code in `Subject.ts`:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L86
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L56

Comment: oh, thanks, it makes point. However, I tried to fix it according to your sugestions and second variant now is working. But third still loses second message. http://jsfiddle.net/e9cm00tg/  
  
btw, it means that @Effects in the ngrx working wrong? I will never return any Completed collections to the result? But in their exaple they send array as result and as I understan it works?https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/effects/collection.ts#L48

Comment: I don't know what do you expect to be the "second message". I recommend you to test this in isolation without messing with the other examples. This http://jsfiddle.net/yphp4q5L/ behaves as it should. Just be aware you're using `switchMap()` and the second  `switchMap()` returns `Rx.Observable.empty()` (which is just a `complete` notification).

Comment: I understand, http://jsfiddle.net/vhunpu66/ now it works. Means we can't only send two messages for one Effect. In this case we rewrite waiting observable (switch it on another). And merge prevents recieving Complete event to the Subject.

Comment: My main idea was to understand how Effects in ngrx works. I tried to make it simple and test :) Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how is this implemented in `ngrx`. With the `merge()` operator the merged Observable sends `complete` notification and `merge()` unsubscribes from it automatically. Maybe try to simplify what you want to do because your demo isn't that simple and post another question. Btw, if you're unsure what each operator does have a look at the source code because it's usually not that hard to understand. For example `toArray()` https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/toArray.ts