# How to set a timeout on a RxJS Observable with a cache throught `.publishReplay()`?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I created an Observable that caching their results for some period of time. The example is great and very useful !! But I couldn't set a timeout for the item producer. I was trying to use the timeout operator within `mockDataFetch()` but after the first failed item, the stream couldn't be recovered.
How to achieve a `mockDataFetch` with a timeout?

This is exactly what I did:

```
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

var counter = 1;
var updateRequest = Observable.defer(() => mockDataFetch())
    .publishReplay(1, 1000)
    .refCount();

function mockDataFetch() {
    return Observable.of(counter++)
        .delay(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))
        .timeout(50);
}

function mockHttpCache() {
    return updateRequest
        .take(1);
}
```

On the other hand, What happens if get an Excpetion within the `mockDataFetch`? I would expect that on the next item (after 1000 ms, as it's defined in the `publishReplay` method) the observable emits a new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I should update the example and add this use-case because this is a pretty common situation (anyway, I'm glad you find it useful!).

When the Observable returned from `mockDataFetch()` sends error/complete notification the Subject inside marks itself as stopped (see explanation [Rx.Subject loses events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786396/rx-subject-loses-events/41789882#41789882)) so it won't reemit any items. You can ideally catch all errors with `catch()` operator inside `mockDataFetch()`:

```
function mockDataFetch() {
    return Observable.of(counter++)
        .delay(Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))
        .timeout(50)
        .catch(err => Observable.of('This request is broken.'));
}
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/jiguti/5/edit?js,console

Output from this could look for example like the following:

```
Response 0: This request is broken.
Response 50: This request is broken.
Response 200: This request is broken.
Response 1200: 2
Response 1500: 2
Response 3500: This request is broken.
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!! I followed your proposal.
I hoped to find a way to be able to receive an error and at the same time keep the observable available for some future observers. I understand that  according to the ReactiveX specification it's not possible to receive a new item after an error or a complete notification, but maybe having an observable that wrap other, it's still possible to get a similar effect. That is, the first observable intercepts the emissions of its underline observable and in case of an error, it builds a new observable for future subscriptions.