# Why connectable observable get execute only once

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a connectable observable that will get connected, when the other stream executed:

```
const source1 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .do(() => console.log('Do Something!'))
  .map(() => "Always connected.")
  .publish();

source1.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));

const connect = () => {
  let c = false;
  return () => {
    if (!c) {
       console.log("Get connected");
       source1.connect();
       c = true;
    }
  }
}


const source2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
   .do(() => console.log("execute!"))
   .do(connect())
   .switchMapTo(source1);

source2.subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

The output

```
"execute!"
"Get connected"
"Do Something!"
"Always connected."
```

Further clicks on the document `source1` will be not subscribe anymore and my question is, why?

Answer (score 1):

You've encountered exactly this situations: [Rx.Subject loses events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786396/rx-subject-loses-events/41789882#41789882)

If you update the first part of your example you'll see that the Subject receives a `complete` notification:

```
const source1 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .do(() => console.log('Do Something!'), null, () => console.log('source1 complete'))
  .map(() => "Always connected.")
  .publish();
```

This marks that Subject as closed and it won't reemit any values ant further.

See my linked answer above for more detailed information. Also you might have a look at [On The Subject Of Subjects (in RxJS)](https://medium.com/@benlesh/on-the-subject-of-subjects-in-rxjs-2b08b7198b93#.slh0m24io) (paragramp *Subjects Are Not Reusable*) by Ben Leash (lead developer of RxJS 5.

Comment: Do you have any proposed solutions? Surely this is a common pattern where you want to execute an observable multiple times. I am trying to implement something similar with RxSwift where I have a connectable observable that wraps a network request. If the network request fails, then I'd like to be able to re-connect...