# How to force publishReplay() to resubscribe?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm very new to RxJS and here's my story. I want a "session" observable so new subscribers will always get current session and then all new sessions if they can appear. So I wrote something like this:

```
var session = Rx.Observable.from([0,1,3])
  .do(x => console.log("Useful job"))
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();

var subscr1 = session.subscribe( x => {
    console.log("sub1 = " +x)
    //subscr1.unsubscribe();
})

console.log("Completed");
subscr1.unsubscribe();

session.subscribe( x => {
  console.log("sub2 = " +x)
});
```

And the output is:

```
Useful job
sub1 = 0
Useful job
sub1 = 1
Useful job
sub1 = 3
Completed
sub2 = 3
```

Why there's no useful job when sub2 subscribes? I expect it to be completely cold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `.publishReplay()` is the number of items it'll replay so you could use `.publishReplay(3)` if you know you can always expect only 3.

If you want to replay the entire sequence you could first collect all its items with `toArray()`, store the array in the `ReplaySubject` and then just flatten the array to individual values.

```
var session = Rx.Observable.from([0,1,3])
  .toArray()
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount()
  .concatAll();
```

Note that `toArray()` doesn't emit anything until its source completes.

EDIT: I see what's the problem now.

Your approach is correct but the problem is in the `Observable.from` and the Subject used inside `publishReplay()`. The source Observable emits three items and send `complete` notification. When the Subject receives a `complete` or `error` notification it marks itself as `stopped` and won't reemit any items any more. And this is exactly what happens in your example.

If you emit values manually without sending `complete` it'll work as you expected.

```
// var session = Rx.Observable.from([0,1,3])
var session = Rx.Observable.create(subscriber => {
    subscriber.next(0);
    subscriber.next(1);
    subscriber.next(3);
  })
  .do(x => console.log("Useful job"))
  .publishReplay(1)
  .refCount();
```

This prints to console:

```
Useful job
sub1 = 0
Useful job
sub1 = 1
Useful job
sub1 = 3
Completed
sub2 = 3
Useful job
sub2 = 0
Useful job
sub2 = 1
Useful job
sub2 = 3
```

See the same problem: [Rx.Subject loses events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786396/rx-subject-loses-events/41789882)

Comment: Sorry, that was just a sample. The original "session" actually is rather complex. It connects to EventSource, does lots of things. And then emits "session" object. At some point it can reconnect and emit "new session" object. Normally it ends only on "logout event".

Now on next "login" event I want it to repeat the session observable on second reconnect. And its not like this.

Comment: @norekhov Can you make a demo simulating this issue? I probably don't understand what's the order of events and what is `session` instead.

Comment: Imagine Rx.Observable.from([0,1,3]) is an observable which rarely emits new sessions. At some point session "3" becomes inactive. Second observable receives "3" while i want session observable to be restarted.

Comment: Something like shareReplay supposed to do.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. A session is an Observable itself? So instead of `Rx.Observable.from([0,1,3])` you have Observable emitting Observables?

Comment: Sorry English is not my native. Yes, instead of Rx.Observable.from([0,1,3]) I have an observable which does some "job" and than sometimes emits. But second subscriber doesn't start this job! Seems it's because of publishReplay(1)

Comment: @norekhov I think I'd need to see a demo that demonstrates how it doesn't work...

Comment: I found a solution. Replace .publishReplay with   .multicast(() => new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)). And magically it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution to this.

Replace .publishReplay(1) with .multicast(() => new Rx.ReplaySubject(1)). So basically I replace a subject with a subjectFactory.

And then it works as expected. So it becomes absolutely cold when everyone unsubscribes.

Comment: Just be aware that now every subscriber has its own instance of `ReplaySubject` (the `ReplaySubject` isn't shared among all subscribers as with `.publishReplay(1)`.

Comment: @martin No they don't. Every new subscriber will receive the last value that was passed through, which means the ReplaySubject is shared.