# Subjects subscribing to observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following simple code:

```
let a: Observable<any> = Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]).share();
let b: Subject<any> = new Subject();

a.subscribe(b)
a.subscribe(value => console.log("New observable value: " + value));
b.subscribe(value => console.log("New subject value: " + value));

b.next("value1");
b.next("value2");
```

The only console lines I see are the ones with "New observable value: " for each of the values in the array. If I comment out line 3, then I get all the "New observable value" lines and the "New subject value" lines, but the subjects do not of course get any of the values omitted by the observable (part of the array).

So basic question - why is this? Why doesn't my subject see any of the array elements 1,2,3,4,5? It subscribes to the observable, so it should get these events (`share()` should broadcast to all subscribers), but this seems to be a misunderstanding on my part.

What I'm looking for here is to make a single subscription to the subject, and see all the values that come in from the observable plus any values emitted via the call to `next()`. Is my code wrong, or am I trying to do things the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic issue is the order of your subscriptions, by the time you are subscribing your `console.log` the `Subject` already received the data. (Check out the code-sample below to see it running)

The second issue, why the `next("value1")` is not working, is because `a.subscribe(b)` will also call the `.complete()` on `b` after the emission of `1,2,3,4,5`.

```js
let a = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]).share();
let b = new Rx.Subject();

b.subscribe(value => console.log("New subject value: " + value));
a.subscribe(value => console.log("New observable value: " + value));
a.subscribe(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

**One** way how to fix this: Don't subscribe the complete `Subject`, but just the `next`-call. Keep in mind though, that this is just **one** way to get this to work, depending on your specific case there might be a better solution available.

```js
let a = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]).share();
let b = new Rx.Subject();

b.subscribe(value => console.log("New subject value: " + value));
a.subscribe(value => console.log("New observable value: " + value));
a.subscribe(data => b.next(data));

b.next("value1");
b.next("value2");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Downvote bot I think! Thanks for your answer, that clears everything up for me :-).

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic problem with Subjects and their internal state.

When you call `a.subscribe(b)` the Subject receives all items from the source Observable `a` and also the `complete` notification which marks it as stopped. You can see it here in the source code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L86
Then all other signals are ignored as you can see for yourself here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subject.ts#L56

This means that this Subject instance will never emit anything again. It's done forever. You can see that the `complete` signal is really send with the `do()` operator:

```
a.do(val => console.log('do: ' + val), null, () => console.log('do: complete'))
  .subscribe(b)
```

See demo: https://jsbin.com/bepupor/1/edit?js,console

So in your case you want to protect the Subject `b` from receiving the `complete` notification. You can do this by manually taking and pushing only the `next` signals:

```
a.subscribe(val => b.next(val));
```

See demo: https://jsbin.com/bepupor/4/edit?js,console

Another very similar question to yours: [Rx.Subject loses events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786396/rx-subject-loses-events/41789882#41789882)

Comment: The links to that source code are helpful, thanks for those. I feel stupid, I stepped through that code and just missed what was right in front of me!